# Handling Multiple images in svg image Android

Tags: android

I am working on a simple app in SDK Android and i have the follwing problem:
I have already converted my png. images in SVG and now i want to make them interract. 
The problem is that the whole image is made up from other images or text fields etc.
So, as i have saved it in .svg format i want to find a way to handle for example the button, when clicked, that exists at the center of my photo, the scroll bar at the bottom, when clicked etc in order to go to another svg image. I don't know how i could handle them seperately, as i save the whole image as svg that contains all the above parts..

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear if you want to combine multiple bitmap or you need to manage svg files (load and display)

Comment: I have saved my png image from illustrator into svg. Then i have added code in my MianActivity.java in order to enable accepting svg and i have loaded my start image whci i can see in the simulator when i run the app. The problem is now that my svg image consist of multiple iamges. For exapmple, int the middle there is a round image and just below there is text. When i click either the image or the text i want o go to the next svg image that i will determine. At the bottom the is a scroll button. When i click this i want to go to another svg image i select in my code.

Comment: Continuing the above i don't know how to handle them seperately in order to add code to continue the interraction betwwen the svg images.. Any helpful code?

Comment: But, how are you handling svg files? using some libraries? I know Android can't do it natively. For example I use an external library: http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Comment: I have created a raw folder in my res folder and i have inside all my converted svg images. So far, i have code for loading my strat svg image but in order to go to the netx one i have to write code in which, when i click e.g. the txet in the center to go to the next one.

Comment: So you're using svg as a container with multiple raw images and you want to display the one in the first leve, then the one in the second leve... ?

Comment: when i click the booton scroll bar, that ispart of the whole image i want to go to another svg. Consequently, i have to find a way to isolate the partsb of the image that i want to be click and then add code to go to the next image i want. Nevertheless, i haven't found a way so far since now my app handles it as a single image, without containing the individual parts

Comment: No. not like that. All the images are designed and they are cropped and converted into svg. But is not simple images. I mean these are the windows appearing in my simulator. the first window contains the fisrt svg image whick includes a logo image, a button for back, a scrool bar in the bottomm etc.. But they are not seperate. the arre affronted as a united image. But since every part will be a different option (click on text go to an image and scroll goes to another) i havn;t found a way to make it work.\

Comment: Edit your question and refine it, don't put code on comments!